# Logout SAML using Azure AD

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have created an Enterprise application in Microsoft Azure for SSO. I have configured the **Identity**, **Reply Url** and **Logout url** of my application. My aim is to make my application SAML compliant.

I'm able to authenticate my user using the function specified in the Reply Url. The function is getting hit and the parameter SAMLResponse receives a base64 encoded string which I'm able to use to authenticate the user in my system.

Similarly when a user Logs out of Office365/AD a the logout function specified in the Logout Url when configuring the application is getting called. I'm receiving an encoded/encrypted string in the parameter SAMLRequest. I would like to know if there are any means by which I could decode the string or know the user who is trying to logout of SSO so that I could log that user out of my system and release the License that the user consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAML string is Base64 encoded and Deflated. So doing the reverse would give you the SAMLRequest xml. The SessionIndex can be used to identify the user by checking it with the sessionIndex received when logging in.

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(SAMLRequest));
DeflateStream deflate = new DeflateStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
string doc = new StreamReader(deflate, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
```